# How do you put a shaders mod into pixelmon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

I have Technic launcher and the shaders mod is the GLSL shaders mod, I am newer to Minecraft and computers so please be patient and help me step by step I will greatly appreciate it. Pixelmon does in fact run forge and the version of Pixelmon is 2.3.4 please help.

Comment: Shaders is not a ForgeMod (i think) so compatibility issues may exist

Answer (score 1):

Since both Mods **ARE** Forge mods this means that when forge is installed you will have a mods folder in your .minecraft folder.

Shaders mod is compatible with all versions up to 1.7.10 and so you simply download the Forge version of the mod and copy that into the mods folder.

The mod page can be found [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1286604-shaders-mod-v2-3-18-updated-by-karyonix) as you can see below there will be a choice of Forge or Non-Forge.

Once it is installed when you open minecraft and go to options you will see a shaders button. Click that and you should see a button to open shaders folder. This is when you copy your shaders to. the most popular shader tends to be SEUS 10.1 which can be found [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1280299-sonic-ethers-unbelievable-shaders-v10-1). Just download and place into your Shaders Folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you navigate to your .Technic or something like that folder and goto modpacks then click on it that is where the mods folder should be so add them there.

*** Make sure the game is closed when you do it though ***

Then reopen the game. Hey presto you installed another mod to it

Please note this only works with forge mods, I had a lot of fun with Optifine in Pixelmon with the shaders it worked fine for me so should for you.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the mods simply are not compatable with pixelmon sorry :(

Comment: Not true i have used it many times with pixelmod